# What is the song that Lupin plays at the end?

Tags: soundtrack, harry-potter, the-prisoner-of-azkaban

What is the song Lupin plays at the end of *Prisoner of Azkaban*, when he's resigning, *not* the one with the boggart?

I already know the boggart scene one, it is *Hot Liquorice* by Dick Walters, but I am unsure about the one when he's resigning and packing up.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about soundtrack identification that will not give further understanding to the plot.

Comment: For the record, it is a piece of stock music called "Jungle Jazz Room" by Steve Gray. It doesn't seem to be on Spotify but this wiki page cites a link to play it: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Witchita_Banana#cite_note-4

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked on various forums for a long time with no answer I'm afraid, I have personally trawled through hours of really good swing music trying to find it. To no avail, each time I think "its got to be by **__**" no joy

All I can conclude that is a piece of stock music, or a throwaway by John Williams. I'd love to be proved wrong though as it really is a catchy tune

Comment: Possibly a public domain big band number, which would explain the lack of credits everywhere.